# Laravel 7 Relation between User and Listing not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I am trying to make a relation with a listing and user in my laravel app. But the relation is not working. Here is my codes:

**Listing.php (Model)**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Listing extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User.php (Model)**

```
public function listing() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Listing');
}
```

**DashboardController.php (Controller)**

```
public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        return view('dashboard')->with('listings', $user->listings);
    }
```

**and dashboard.blade.php (view)**

```
<div class="panel-body">
                        {{ dd($listings) }}
                        @if(count($listings))
                            <table class="table table-stripped">
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Company Name</th>
                                    <th>Address</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    @foreach($listings as $listing)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{ $listing->name }}</td>
                                            <td>{{ $listing->address }}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endforeach
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        @endif
                    </div>
```

But it's not passing data with 'listings' variable. it's showing 'listings' variable is NULL.

Can you guys please help me.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure, you are listings is not empty?

Comment: Can you show the table structure of your database ? Like primary keys ?

Comment: This is the table structure: https://imgur.com/a/YzLI3Q1

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing something here

```php
public function index()
{
    $user = User::find(auth()->id());

    // $user->listings or $user->listing ? because in User.php it's listing not listings

    return view('dashboard')->with('listings', $user->listing);
}
```

Comment: Maybe I have checked that 10 times. but still didn't find the mistake. :D :D :D Thanks once again.

Comment: yeah sometimes we do really silly mistakes, we can't notice them :D :D 

Answer (score 2):

for best practice add the foreign key in the relation ship 
something like this :

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User' , 'id');
    }
```